# Optimize nutch performance on hadoop cluster

Tags: performance, hadoop, nutch, cloudera, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to optimize nutch performance for crawling sites. Now i test performance on small hadoop cluster, only two nodes 32gb RAM, cpu Intel Xeon E3 1245v2 4c/8t.
My config for nutch http://pastebin.com/bBRHpFuq

So, the problem: fetching jobs works not optimal. Some reduce task has 4k pages for fetching, some 1kk pages. For example see screenshot https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B98dgNxOqKMvT1doOVVPUU1PNXM/edit Some reduce task finished in 10 minutes, but one task work 11 hours and still continue working, so it's like a bottle neck when i have 24 reduce task, but works only one.

May be someone can give usefull advices or links where i can read about problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was problem in Nutch, it takes about 50 000 000 from one site and 500 000 from all other. So when it creating queue by host we see one extremely big queue and other very small.